# How can I pass a error 500 message to my error template?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, error-handling

Using Syfmony2, I have created custom error templates, in my case it is

```
/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig
```

and looks somehow like this

```
<html>
  </body>
    <h1>ERROR {{ status_code }}</h1>
    <p>{{ status_text }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I now throw an error with a message in it:

```
throw new Exception('There is something wrong in the state of Denkmark.');
```

I would expect that the message is shown on the rendered error template. Instead, it only shows a standard message:

> Internal Server Error

However, when I run in dev mode it shows the correct message (but on the Symfony2 standard error template). Why is the message in prod mode hidden? Who am I writing the messages for? For the dev log?

(How) can I force to show the message on my template in prod mode as well?

Comment: What do you mean with "standard error template"? Into logs?

Comment: No, I mean this develop error template with the sweet black monster and the green bubble: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6TzhM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will nedd to make a custom template, EventListener and register the EventListener:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/AcmeExceptionListener.php 
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class AcmeExceptionListener
{
  public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
  {
     // You get the exception object from the received event
     $exception = $event->getException();
     $message = sprintf(
         'My Error says: %s with code: %s',
         $exception->getMessage(),
         $exception->getCode()
    );

    // Customize your response object to display the exception details
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($message);

    // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
    // holds status code and header details
    if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
         $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
         $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
    } else {
         $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    // Send the modified response object to the event
    $event->setResponse($response);
  }
}
```

and you will need to register the listenter:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method:    
onKernelException }
```

source:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is correct as `Exception` may contains some "internal" information and in production enviroment those infos should not be displayed.

What you can do is costumize the 404 page or use your own logic to display something when an exception occurs but you can't rely on symfony2 standard logic as it's not compatible with your

For costumize 404 page, you should ovveride default template by placing your own error page here `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`

For your own logic: simply use an [event listener/subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) that will render a page upon some exceptions

Comment: Uh okay, I already assumed something like this. That means I should create my own exception? Probably with my own error code, e.g. in the 460s to not use existing ones and write a error460.html.twig with a static error message?

Comment: I'm not talking about the 404 errors, I already have a `error404.html.twig`. I'm looking for error 500s.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel: Implement your own logic as I said before ;)